# How to see the full request and full response in JMETER CSV

Tags: jmeter

I have a question about running jmeter in non ui mode.
I run my test plan, and export it to csv (the results).
I have some http requests samplers in the test plan.
the problem is that I not see it in the csv.
I want to see exactly what I sent in the request for manual debug and I not see it.
I have the lable and the response code.
but I would like to see the full request that I sent and the full response, not response message or  response code.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps (they are also best practices with jmeter community) for what you are trying to achieve.

**Add a KPI Writer**

1. Add a listener `Simple Data Writer` to your test plan/thread group. Name it as `KPI writer`
2. It will write only the checked items and in csv format.
3. Configure it as below.
   [image]

**Add a Detailed Writer** *(this is what you need as per your question)*

1. Add a listener `Simple Data Writer` to your test plan/thread group. Name it as `Detail writer`
2. **DO NOT enable** this during a load test as it will consume a lot of memory and will make jmeter laggy or may crash during the test. This will write request, response and other details in the jtl file and in xml format.
3. Configure it as below.
   [image]

**Add an Error Writer**

1. Add a listener `Simple Data Writer` to your test plan/thread group. Name it as `Error writer`
2. You can enable this during a load test and it will write details about the response and failure reason in the event of errors. This will write response and details about the result in the jtl file in xml format.
3. Configure it as below.
   [image]

Above configurations on the script will give you three files on the completion of the test: `kpi.jtl, detail.jtl and error.jtl` which is sufficient to debug your test or get more details for your report.

Comment: Read more here http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners

Comment: will it worked if I run it on non gui mode?  I want to see this fields in the csv that is the results. can you please specify how to make jmeter non gui know the http requests? and write them in the results?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by 'can you please specify how to make jmeter non gui know the http requests? ' but it will work on non gui mode.